# Relative homology of $M\times M$ to diagonal

Tags: algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, homology-cohomology, manifolds-with-boundary

Let $M$ be a compact manifold. I want to understand why
$$
\beta_i(M\times M, M) = \beta_i(M\times M)-\beta_i(M),
$$
where $\beta_i$ denotes the $i$th Betti number and we identify $M$ with the diagonal in $M\times M$.

Taking a tubular neighborhood $U\subset M\times M$ of $M$, we define a manifold with boundary by $N:= M\times M - U$. By excision we have
$$
H_i(N,\partial N) \cong H_i(M\times M, M).
$$
Here I am stuck. Is this the right approach? If so, how can one compute $H_i(N,\partial N)$? If not, what is?

Comment: The diagonal inclusion $\Delta:M\rightarrow M\times M$ has a retraction (project onto either factor). Thus when you look at the long exact sequence in homology of the pair $(M\times M,M)$, you find that it splits up into a sequence of short exact sequences. Working with rational coefficients you can extract the desired equation.

Comment: Thank you @Tyrone! That makes sense.